# Get time length of friendship in network R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, igraph, data-manipulation

I have a network dataset of adolescent friendships over 7 waves. I'm trying to get the length of a given dyad (directed friendship).

SAMPLE HAVE DATA:

```
 ego    alter   wave
   1        5      1
   1        4      1
   1        5      2
   1        2      2
   1        3      2
   2        8      1
   2        8      2
   2        8      3
   3        4      1
   3        7      1
   3        6      1
   3        6      2
   3        7      3
   3        6      3
```

WANT DATA:

```
 ego    alter   friendship_length
   1        5     2  
   1        4     1 
   1        2     1 
   1        3     1  
   2        8     3        
   3        4     1 
   3        7     1 
   3        6     3
```

Here's what I've already tried:

```
edges_wide <- edges_long %>% 
              select(ego, alter, wave) %>%
              group_by(ego, alter) %>% 
              mutate(col=seq_along(ego))%>% # add a column indicator
              spread(key=col, value=wave)
```

Which gives me this:

```
 ego    alter   col3    col4    col5
   1        5      1       2      NA
   1        4      1      NA      NA                    
   1        2      2      NA      NA
   1        3      2      NA      NA
   2        8      1       2       3            
   3        4      1      NA      NA
   3        7      1       3      NA
   3        6      1       2       3
```

From here I'm not sure how to get the wave span (length) of the directed friendship, including not counting non consecutive nominations (like ego 3 alter 7).

Comment: The following generates your desired output, but I am suspicious it is coincidence. I don't know how it would perform on other data.  `edges %>% group_by(ego, alter) %>% summarise(sum(wave == seq(wave)))`

Comment: For the full dataset this seems to only work for friends nominated one time. Any dyads that appear in more than one wave, like ego 3 alter 7, get a 0 for the friendship length. Any idea why that is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to have a shorter solution.

If I understand correctly, you want to count only the first occurrences of subsequent waves in which alter and ego have a relationship. Therefore, we can add a group id with `row_number()`, adjust for the fact that sometimes waves start after 1 with `min(wave)-1`, and then just count the observations where `wave` and this modified `id` coincide. For a given pair, as soon as one wave is skipped in the data, the two indices will differ.

```
d %>% 
  arrange(wave) %>% 
  group_by(ego, alter) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number() + min(wave) - 1) %>%
  summarise(friendship_lenght = sum(wave==id))

# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   ego [3]
    ego alter friendship_lenght
  <int> <int>             <int>
1     1     2                 1
2     1     3                 1
3     1     4                 1
4     1     5                 2
5     2     8                 3
6     3     4                 1
7     3     6                 3
8     3     7                 1
```

**EDIT**
Addressing the new comment. We want to count the longest duration of consecutive friendship ties. `row_number()` can be used to create a unique friendship-phase-id, by pair. Friendship in the first consecutive waves will all be given the same integer, and so forth for all subsequent consecutive friendships. Thus we can count how many times each single integer shows up, and take the max:

```
dd %>% 
  arrange(wave) %>% 
  group_by(ego, alter) %>%
  count(wave - row_number() ) %>% 
  summarise(friendship_lenght = max(n)) 

# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   ego [3]
    ego alter friendship_lenght
  <int> <int>             <dbl>
1     1     2                 1
2     1     3                 1
3     1     4                 1
4     1     5                 2
5     2     8                 3
6     3     4                 1
7     3     6                 3
8     3     7                 1
9     3     8                 3
```

Data

```
library(dplyr)
d <-  read.table(text = "
             ego    alter   wave
   1        5      1
   1        4      1
                 1        5      2
                 1        2      2
                 1        3      2
                 2        8      1
                 2        8      2
                 2        8      3
                 3        4      1
                 3        7      1
                 3        6      1
                 3        6      2
                 3        7      3
                 3        6      3", header=T)


dd <-  read.table(text = "
                 ego    alter   wave
                 1        5      1
                 1        4      1
                 1        5      2
                 1        2      2
                 1        3      2
                 2        8      1
                 2        8      2
                 2        8      3
                 3        4      1
                 3        7      1
                 3        6      1
                 3        6      2
                 3        7      3
                 3        6      3
                 3 8 2
                 3 8 3
                 3 8 8
                 3 8 6
                 3 8 7", header=T)
```

Comment: Ah I didn't specify, I do want to count consecutive friendships even if they appear later in the waves. For example, if A nominates B in wave 1, wave 3, wave 4, and wave 5, their friendship length should be 3. Does that make sense? Other than that part this works perfectly

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

One more possibility.

First, let's make a function that counts the length of a consecutive sequence:

```
get_seq_len <- function(s){
  if(length(s) == 0) return(0)
  if(length(s) == 1) return(1)
  consec_lengths <- rle(c(1, s[-1] - s[-length(s)]))$lengths
  return(consec_lengths[1])
}
```

We can verify it works:

```
get_seq_len(numeric(0))
#> 0
get_seq_len(1)
#> 1
get_seq_len(1:4)
#> 4
get_seq_len(c(1:4, 4:5))
#> 4 (because not consecutive)
get_seq_len(c(1,3))
#> 1 (not consecutive)
```

Then we can simply use nesting to do that for each pair:

```
edges_long %>%
  group_by(ego, alter) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(vec_waves = map(data, ~ as.numeric(unlist(.x)))) %>% # convert dataframe to vector
  mutate(len = map_dbl(vec_waves, get_seq_len))
# A tibble: 8 x 5
# Groups:   ego, alter [8]
#     ego alter data             vec_waves   len
#    <dbl> <dbl> <list>           <list>    <dbl>
# 1     1     5 <tibble [2 x 1]> <dbl [2]>     2
# 2     1     4 <tibble [1 x 1]> <dbl [1]>     1
# 3     1     2 <tibble [1 x 1]> <dbl [1]>     1
# 4     1     3 <tibble [1 x 1]> <dbl [1]>     1
# 5     2     8 <tibble [3 x 1]> <dbl [3]>     3
# 6     3     4 <tibble [1 x 1]> <dbl [1]>     1
# 7     3     7 <tibble [2 x 1]> <dbl [2]>     1
# 8     3     6 <tibble [3 x 1]> <dbl [3]>     3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a terrible way to do it but this worked!

```
edges_wide <- edges_long %>% 
              select(ego, alter, wave) %>%
              group_by(ego, alter) %>% 
              mutate(col=seq_along(ego))%>% # add a column indicator
              spread(key=col, value=wave) %>%
              rename(col1 = "1", col2 = "2", col3 = "3",
                     col4 = "4", col5 = "5", col6 = "6",
                     col7 = "7") 
          
edges_wide <- edges_wide %>% 
              mutate(wave1 = case_when(col1 == 1 ~ 1,
                                       TRUE ~ as.numeric(0))) %>%
              mutate(wave2 = case_when(col1 == 2 | col2 == 2 ~ 1,
                                       TRUE ~ as.numeric(0))) %>%
              mutate(wave3 = case_when(col1 == 3 | col2 == 3 | col3 == 3 ~ 1,
                                       TRUE ~ as.numeric(0))) %>%
              mutate(wave4 = case_when(col1 == 4 | col2 == 4 | col3 == 4 | col4 == 4 ~ 1,
                                       TRUE ~ as.numeric(0))) %>%
              mutate(wave5 = case_when(col1 == 5 | col2 == 5 | col3 == 5 | col4 == 5 | col5 == 5 ~ 1,
                                       TRUE ~ as.numeric(0))) %>%
              mutate(wave6 = case_when(col1 == 6 | col2 == 6 | col3 == 6 | col4 == 6 | col5 == 6 | col6 == 6 ~ 1,
                                       TRUE ~ as.numeric(0))) %>%
              mutate(wave7 = case_when(col1 == 7 | col2 == 7 | col3 == 7 | col4 == 7 | col5 == 7 | col6 == 7 | col7 == 7 ~ 1,
                                       TRUE ~ as.numeric(0))) %>%
              select(ego, alter, wave1, wave2, wave3, wave4, wave5, wave6, wave7)
                   
most_consecutive_val = function(x, val = 1) {
   with(rle(x), if(all(values != val)) 0 else max(lengths[values == val]))
}

edges_wide$span <- apply(edges_wide[-c(1:2)], MARGIN = 1, most_consecutive_val)
```